# How can I listen to a String variable change and perform an action when there is a change?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to execute a function, lets call it `myFunction()` if a variable `_myString` is changed, but have this happen on the fly?

What I have is a `textfield` with a `controller`

```
var _myString;

const TextField(
        controller:_controller
)
```

Now elsewhere in my widget tree, I have a *button* that can change the value of `_myString`, in this case I'm changing '_myString' to 'Testing'

```
GestureDetector(
     onTap:(){ _myString = 'Testing'; }
     child: Text('Testing')
)
```

Now what I'm hoping to achieve is that when the value of `_myString` changes in any way, I can perform some action of my choosing.  In this case, I want to edit the TextField using the `_controller`, but I don't only want to do that, but a few other things, so I think its better to listen to changes in that variable and then execute a function

```
void myFunction(){
///Do some stuff
}
```

I'm using `riverpod` for state management in my app, and I was thinking I could try to use it, but have no idea how to use it to watch a single variable, I'm more familiar with using it for entire widgets.  Alternatively using riverpod for something like this might be overkill.

I just don't know how to approach this problem, so any guidance would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you could use a `ValueNotifier` for this, a value notifier is a class that holds some value and "notifies" its listeners when this value changes. It is a simpler version of `ChangeNotifier`:

```
ValueNotifier<String> _myString = ValueNotifier<String>('');
```

With the above, whenever you want to read or write the value, use the value getter/setter:

```
print(_myString.value);
_myString.value = 'some value';
```

Now, to listen to changes you should use the `addListener` method:

```
@override
initState() {
  // update _controller with value whenever _myString changes
  _myString.addListener(() => _controller.text = _myString.value);

  // print value on change
  _myString.addListener(() => print(_myString.value));

  // do stuff
  _myString.addListener(myFunction)
}
```